# Why does my Outlook Custom Form Custom Property Script not run?

Tags: vba, forms, outlook, scripting

1). In Outlook, I have cloned the Standard Message Form IPM.Note to a Custom Form in my Personal Forms Library IPM.Note.myMessage.

2). I turned on page #2 of the forms, and placed on it: a Check box and a Text Box.

3). Under View Code (bringing up the script editor) I inserted the following code by doing View Code -> Script -> Event Handler in Developer Mode.

```
Sub Item_CustomPropertyChange(ByVal Name)
    msgbox ("Hello")
End Sub

Function Item_CustomAction(ByVal Action, ByVal NewItem)
    msgbox ("Hello")
End Function
```

4). I published the form to my Personal Form Library as myMessage

5). In Trust Center I have "Enable all macros (not recommended; potentially dangerous code can run)

6). I enabled Scripts for my Custom Message Class IPM.Note.myMessage by adding the registry keys in the article:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Custom-form-script-is-now-disabled-by-default-bd8ea308-733f-4728-bfcc-d7cce0120e94

7). I am running Outlook Microsoft 365 for Enterprise / version 2004 Build 12730.20206 Click-To-Run

8) I am Office Microsoft Fork program, M365 OuterRing, Monthly Fork Builds that have been promoted from Dogfood.

9). I am running Windows 10 with all updates applied.

Comment: What exactly did you do to trigger event handlers in your custom form?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the steps described in the [Forms with VBScript do not work with Terminal Services in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/302003/forms-with-vbscript-do-not-work-with-terminal-services-in-outlook) article.

### Install Microsoft Office with an additional property to let the VBScript component to be installed

To do this, follow these steps:

1. Determine the globally unique identifier (GUID) for the product that you just installed. If you installed Outlook, use that product GUID. If you installed Office Professional Plus 2010, use that product GUID. For more information about how to determine the GUID of the product that you installed, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:

   - [3120274](https://support.microsoft.com/EN-US/help/3120274)  Description of the numbering scheme for product code GUIDs in Office 2016
   - [2786054](https://support.microsoft.com/EN-US/help/2786054)  Description of the numbering scheme for product code GUIDs in Office 2013
   - [2186281](https://support.microsoft.com/EN-US/help/2186281) Description of the numbering scheme for product code GUIDs in Office 2010
   - [928516](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/928516) Description of the numbering scheme for product code GUIDs in 2007 Office suites and programs
2. After you have the product GUID, run the following command line:

```
msiexec /i <Product Code GUID> ADDLOCAL=OutlookVBScript /qb
```

In this command, `<Product Code GUID>` is a placeholder for your product GUID.

For example, if you have Office Professional Plus 2016 installed, your product GUID would be the following:

```
{90160000-0011-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}
```

In this example, the command line should appear as follows:

```
msiexec /i {90160000-0011-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE} ADDLOCAL=OutlookVBScript /qb
```

Also, I'd suggest trying another Office build. The issue can be specific to a particular Office version and be fixed with future updates.